# Classifying phase portait regarding zero eigenvalue.

Tags: differential

When you have two equations

$x' = 4x -3y$

$y' = 8x -6y$

The solution turns out to be

$x = c_1e^{-2t} + 3c_2$

$y = 2c_1e^{-2t} + 4c_2$

and I understand how the phase portrait is visualized.

However, what I don't understand is that whether or not type of this phase portrait is

considered to be a stable system. one of the solution seems to be approaching $0$

and other solution is a constant. However, we usually assume that determinant of a matrix

which contains these roots are not $0$ so that we can find out the critical points or

equilibrium solution of $x$ to see where the solutions are headed. Therefore, the assumption

of this is violated. Thus, I am not sure what this kind of phase portrait should be

classified as.

Comment: Yes, that is a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this system, we have the equilibrium points as the line:

$$y = \dfrac 43 x$$

You found that the solution to the system is given by:

$$X(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{bmatrix} = c_1 e^{-2t} \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix} + c_2 e^{0t}\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\end{bmatrix} $$

If we draw the phase portrait for this system (red line is the equilibrium line), we have:

[image]

Since the trace of the matrix is negative, we have a line of [*neutrally stable*](https://www.ru.ac.za/media/rhodesuniversity/content/mathematics/documents/thirdyear/linearcontrol/AM32LC4%20Stability.pdf) non-isolated fixed points. Sometimes this is called by other names like stable, but not asymptotically stable or marginally stable, etc.

It is also worth mentioning that in some settings (like [*Control*](https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/EigenvalueStability#Zero_Eigenvalues)), they consider this unstable.